# Regex for Comma Delimited IP Addresses

Tags: regex, list, replace, find, ip

I have a list of IP addresses (each on a new line) that I want to do a find/replace on and make the list comma delimited and on the same line. What would the regex be that would allow me to find all the IP addresses and what would the regex be to make the list comma delimited as mentioned?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(,\n|,?$))
```

Comment: Tried. What have you? Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: Just edited the question to include what I tried so far. Can't figure out how to fix it to get it to work as I want it to.

Comment: @anubhava - Sublime Text 2